# Actualizar un campo recorriendo cada registro

Tags: php, mysql

Quiero actualizar registros en base a una variable `$aux = 110`, por ejemplo. En en la imagen la primera fila tiene un cantidad de 80. Por lo cual debe quedar en cero y pasar al siguiente registro con lo que sobre de `110-80 = 30`. Entonces, al siguiente registro debería quedar `100-30 = 70` y así sucesivamente hasta que quede `$aux=0`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Resultado final:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Agrega el código que llevas, no podemos guiarnos por la imagen

Comment: El concepto de siguiente registro en una base de datos no existe. Tenes que especificar cómo esperás que los registros estén ordenados para hablar de un registro siguiente.